# jsp/servlets filling a drop down box from an array

Tags: java, database, forms, jsp, servlets

hi all I'm trying to create a form that allows you to create a lab for a subject. It has a drop down box where you can select the subjects that are related to that user. However when I go to load the page i get this error `g.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException`, with the current user that I'm using, they should have 2 results

here is my servlet in full

```
import java.io.IOException;


import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CreateLab
 */
@WebServlet("/CreateLab")
public class CreateLab extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CreateLab() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
     int id;
     int capacity; 
     String day = ""; 
     String time = ""; 
     String room = ""; 
     int subject_id;
     int user_id;

    public void init() {
      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
        System.out.println("JDBC driver loaded"); 
      } 
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString()); 
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    } 

    /**Process the HTTP Get request*/ 
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
  ServletException,IOException {  


    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    String sql = "SELECT id,name" +
              " FROM subject " +
            " WHERE user_id="+(Integer)session.getAttribute("id");

    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
        System.out.println("connected");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          System.out.println(res);
          ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
          if (res.next()){
              do{
                   list1.add(res.getString(1));
                   list2.add(res.getString(2));
                   System.out.print(list1.add(res.getString(1)));
                   System.out.print(list2.add(res.getString(2)));

              }while(res.next());
          System.out.println("Outside");
          String[] arr1 = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
          String[] arr2 = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
          System.out.println(list1);
          request.setAttribute("res1", arr1);
          request.setAttribute("res2", arr2);
          request.setAttribute("user_id", user_id);

          }

    }catch (SQLException e) {
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
    } 

      sendRegistrationForm(request, response, false); 
      sendPageHeader(response);
    } 

    /**Process the HTTP Post request*/ 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      sendPageHeader(response); 
      HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
      capacity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("capacity"));

      day = request.getParameter("day"); 
      time = request.getParameter("time"); 
      room = request.getParameter("room"); 
      user_id = (int) session.getAttribute("id");
      subject_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("subject_id")); 

      System.out.print(user_id);

      boolean error = false; 
      String message = null; 
      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con = 
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
        System.out.println("got connection"); 
        System.out.println(id);
        Statement s = con.createStatement(); 

        String sql = "SELECT id FROM user" + 
                " WHERE id='" + user_id + "'";  
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql); 
        if (rs.next()) {
          rs.close(); 
           sql = "INSERT INTO lab" + 
                  " (capacity, day, time, room, subject_id, user_id)" + 
                  " VALUES" + 
                  " ('" +  capacity + "'," + 
                     " '"  +  day + "'," + 
                     " '"  +  time + "'," + 
                     " '"  + room + "','" + subject_id + "','" + user_id + "')"; 

          System.out.println(sql);
          int i = s.executeUpdate(sql); 
          if (i==1) {
            message = "Successfully a new lab class."; 
            response.sendRedirect("Lecturer_labs.jsp");
          } 
        } 
          s.close(); 
          con.close(); 
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
          message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
          error = true; 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
          message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
          error = true; 
        } 
        if (message!=null) {
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
          out.println("<B>" + message + "</B><BR>"); 
          out.println("<HR><BR>"); 
        } 
        if (error==true) 
          sendRegistrationForm(request, response, true); 
        else 
          sendRegistrationForm(request, response, false); 
        sendPageFooter(response); 
      } 

      }
```

here is my jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Mars University Lab System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
<jsp:include page="headerLecturer.jsp"/>


<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div id = "centrecontent">
<br>
<h3>Create Labs</h3>

<%
    String[] list1 = (String[])request.getAttribute("res1");
    String[] list2 = (String[])request.getAttribute("res2"); %>

        <form name ="createLabs" ACTION="CreateLab" method="post">
        Capacity: <input type="text" name="capacity"/><br />
        Day: <input type="text" name="day"/><br />
        Time: <input type="text" name="time"/><br />
        Room: <input type="text" name="room"/><br />
        <select name="subject_id">
        <%
        for(int i=0; i<list1.length; i++)  
        { 
        out.println("<option value="+list1[0]+"> "+list2[i]+" </option>");

        } 
        %>


        </select>
        <input type=SUBMIT value="Submit" name="Submit" />

    </form>
</div>

<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This code has an SQL Injection flaw in the doGet() method. Use prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Which line is causing the NullPointerException?

Comment: for(int i=0; i<list1.length; i++)

Comment: And you're sure the database calls returned a list? Did you try to debug the code? There are some other issues with your code, like thread safety (instance variables in Servlet). In case of database error your JSP will almost always throw a NPE as the lists might not have been set...

Comment: yes the database should spit out 2 results

Answer (score 2):

This code has a serious security flaw in it. You're taking input from the user and passing it into database queries unvetted:

```
day = request.getParameter("day"); 
time = request.getParameter("time"); 
room = request.getParameter("room"); 

sql = "INSERT INTO lab" + 
              " (capacity, day, time, room, subject_id, user_id)" + 
              " VALUES" + 
              " ('" +  capacity + "'," + 
                 " '"  +  day + "'," + 
                 " '"  +  time + "'," + 
                 " '"  + room + "','" + subject_id + "','" + user_id + "')"; 
int i = s.executeUpdate(sql);
```

This can be exploited with an [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Attackers could do harm to your database by passing unexpected things to your form.

It is much safer (and neater) to use prepared statements:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO lab" + 
              " (capacity, day, time, room, subject_id, user_id)" + 
              " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInt(1,   capacity );
// set the rest.
int i = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

To avoid your `NullPointerException`, you could initialize `list1` and `list2` before your try block then setAttribute with them after the catch. This way you'll at least get an empty list for your form when something goes wrong in the try.

Comment: Follow the advice in jdevelop's answer, debug the code in your try block, check what value you have for `user_id`, check if you're getting into the `if(res.next())` block.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the code you posted has more room for improvement, but I'd suggest you to not sink exceptions like you're doing:

```
}catch (SQLException e) {
} 
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

since attribute is not set (null), it may indicate that something went wrong with the code in try-catch block.

I think that there also might be the case when user ID from session is null as well.

Try adding more verbose output (like println) and this will give you much more details about the data flow with your code.

Is that homework? If that's something to be used in production - ouch, it should be completely rewritten.

Comment: yeah, homework  - group assignment just trying to add a little something extra with a drop down box.

Comment: check that there are no exceptions, simply add e.prinStackTrace() in empty catch blocks.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:534)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:457)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause

Comment: please check out the server console or logs, the exception you posted here is from JSP page itself

Answer (score 1):

First of all how will you get the attributes (res1 and res2) before using this u suppose to set this attributes im right.... make sure before using this attributes you are invoking that CreateLab servlet with get method...

And i like to correct some code in your program....

```
Dont open DB connection so many time, if you are open then you must close.
```

Repeated items in list...

```
list1.add(res.getString(1));
list2.add(res.getString(2));
System.out.print(list1.add(res.getString(1)));
System.out.print(list2.add(res.getString(2)));
```

Use following for above

```
list1.add(res.getString(1));
list2.add(res.getString(2));
System.out.print(res.getString(1));
System.out.print(res.getString(2));
```

Use prepared statement to avoid sql injection....

Check that parameters....